# VBA generating random numbers between -35 to +5

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to code a line in VBA that would allow me to generate random numbers between `-35` and `5`. I've used the below formula however, it gives me random numbers between `-5` and `+5`

```
Int((Rnd() * ((-1) ^ Int(Rnd() * 10))) * 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Fix(Rnd() * 41) - 35
```

will do it. This will be uniformly distributed insofar that `Rnd()` is. `Fix` scrubs the decimal portion of a number. You want every number between -35 and 5 inclusive which is 41 numbers. `rnd()` itself never draws 1.

Test the generator with something like

```
Sub test()

    Dim j As Long
    While True
        j = Fix(Rnd() * 41) - 35

        VBA.DoEvents 'so you can break the program once you're done

        If j < -35 Or j > 5 Then
            Stop 'oops
        End If
        If j = -35 Then
            Debug.Print "Yup, I draw on the boundary"
        End If
        If j = 5 Then
            Debug.Print "Yup, I draw on the boundary"
        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Will this work if it was between -35000 and +5000? It might not. I don't think it will ever give positive values

Comment: Yes it would. You'd need `Fix(Rnd() * 40001) - 35000`. Note that will be a `Long` type, not an `Int`.

Comment: sorry I'm being a little hard headed but my code is this and Net3 is defined as range                                                                                      For Each Net3 In Range("C2:C501")
    Net3.Value = Int((Rnd() * ((-1) ^ Fix(Rnd() * 40001) - 35000)))
    Next

Comment: @Yags: Ditch that code and replace with mine. For starters making two drawings on the generator is not a good idea from a statistical perspective (although possibly no worse than the generator itself).

Comment: @Tom: Answers in the answers section please; yes, you could is my first reaction.

Comment: Although it's a solution I didn't intend it as an answer. I was questioning the rational over using non-standard to achieve built in functionality. I'll remove it though

Comment: `Fix(Rnd() * 41) - 35` is an obvious statistical transformation of the built-in generator. It will also work with other VBAs plus VBScript so is arguably more portable. But your answer has an obvious elegance to it. I would upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an uniform distribution:

```
Int(Rnd*41)-35
```

`0<=Rnd<1` (some time back I found `Rnd=1`, but it seams not happening any more)

`0<=Rnd*41<41`

`0<=Int(Rnd*41)<=40`

`-35<=Int(Rnd*41)-35<=5`

From documentation:

> ```
> Int
> Returns the integer portion of a number.
> ```